# shape outside with background :before and :after issue

Tags: html, css

I want the text to flow around my images without creating empty elements so I tried using :before and after. The before works, but the text doesn't flow around the after. Is this possible? Here is my sample code.

```css
#shape {
  margin: 0px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
#shape-content:before {
  width: 30%;
  height: 500px;
  float: left;
  content: "";
  background: url("https://dummyimage.com/200x500/000000/fff") no-repeat;
  -webkit-shape-outside: url("https://dummyimage.com/200x500/000000/fff");
}
#shape-content:after {
  content: "";
  width: 40%;
  float: right;
  height: 600px;
  background: url("https://dummyimage.com/200x500/000000/fff") no-repeat;
  -webkit-shape-outside: url("https://dummyimage.com/200x500/000000/fff");
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: -100px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
#shape-content {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="shape">
  <span id="shape-content">
    Now, the fact is, if it's a woman in front of you that's
    writing the cheque, you will not be waiting long. I have noticed that
    women are very *fast* with cheques, y'know, 'cuz they write out so many
    cheques. The keys, they can never find in their purse, they don't know
    where that is, but the cheque book they got that. They never fumble for
    the cheque book-- the cheque book comes out of a holster: ["draws" imaginary
    book from an imaginary holster] ``Who do I make it out to?... There's my
    ID...''. There's something about a cheque that, to a man, is not masculine.
    I don't know exactly what it is... I think to a man, a cheque is like a note
    from your mother that says ``I don't have any money, but if you'll
    contact these people, I'm sure they'll stick up for me... If you
    just trust me this one time I don't have any money but I have
    these... I wrote on these; is this of any value at all?''
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `:after` is using `position: absolute;`, which is not part of the flow layout, you will need to use another method of positioning if you want it to make the text wrap.

Comment: The reason i used position:absolute is because float: right didnt show up next but under neat the text. So, im still stuck

Comment: I sort of came to a solution with a <br class="right">. Not elegant, but it works.